# Long running Powershell command to to run with schtasks

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have various bits of automation on remote servers which I use through a Python script using [pywinrm](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/). I have lots of Powershell stuff commands I've automated already, but I've never had to run a long running Powershell command however.

I'm now trying to schedule some performance counters to capture during a performance test, and have come up with the following to capture what I want:

```
Start-Job { & Get-counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time", "\Memory\Available Bytes" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 10 | Export-counter -Path $home\Desktop\perf_data.csv -FileFormat CSV }
```

However, as part of my automation, I want to provide a command to schtasks to run this at a particular time across all servers. Currently the process starts with the following command, but no output is produced - I think the task just dies as soon as its started:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Perf Test" /tr "powershell -noexit -command { & Start-Job { & Get-counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time', '\Memory\Available Bytes' -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 10 | Export-counter -Path $home\Desktop\perf_data.csv -FileFormat CSV }}" /sc once /st 16:58:00 /sd 24/01/2018
```

I realise I could make this easier on myself by scheduling a script to run rather than a command, but I'd ideally like to just run this as a command.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: Not sure that $home would be available in the script block

Comment: With all that syntax, use `-EncodedCommand`.  I [recently answered a question for a similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428619/windows-task-for-restart-if-user-not-logged-in#answer-48430373)

Comment: @EBGreen It should be.  It's basically an alias for `$Env:UserProfile`

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1.  Unfortunately it still tries to execute in the same way whether encoded or not.  I think its more to do with getting the task to continue running in the background which is why in my second line of code I'm using `-noexit` which I believe should help me, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using jobs?  I've had bad luck with getting them to work consistently. Also your call operator in the script block doesn't do anything

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 by jobs are you referring to scheduled tasks?  If so, I need this to start at the same time across up to 90 servers, and have used scheduled tasks for this lots of times.  If you're referring to my use of `Start-Job`, I'm no desperately familiar with Powershell, so I might be using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not terribly familiar with counters, but this solution should work for you:

```
$Command = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
    [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(@"
`$CounterParams = @{
    Counter = @(
        '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time'
        '\Memory\Available Bytes'
    )
    SampleInterval = 2
    MaxSamples = 10
}
Get-Counter @CounterParams |
    Export-Counter -Path $Env:UserProfile\Desktop\perf_data.csv -FileFormat CSV }
"@ )
)

schtasks.exe /create /tn "Perf Test" /tr "powershell -NoProfile -EncodedCommand $Command"
```